# E0020 identifier "sleep" is undefined Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, github

The Visual Studio 2019 shows E0020: "Sleep() is undefined" and C3861 'sleep':identifier not found.
I  use "windows.h" but it doesn't work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <dos.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "pthreadVC2.lib")

using namespace std;

..........

int main() {
    pthread_t tid0;
    pthread_t tid1;

    pthread_create(&tid0, NULL, workerThreadFunc, (void*)&tid0);
    pthread_create(&tid1, NULL, workerThreadFunc2, (void*)&tid1);
    
    sleep(1);  // E0020 identifier "sleep" is undefined**
    
    THREADS_CREATED = 1;

    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the "sleep(1)" should like this "Sleep(1)". The letter "s" should be capitalized.